# Arrays for days and matching month

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently doing a course in software development and have been given an assignment im having a little trouble with and be very appreciative if someone could help...This is the task it's in java by the way:

Write a program which will access two arrays.
One array will hold names of the month and the other the number of days in each month.

When the user inputs a month number, the program will return name of month and number of days....

This is the code I have entered so far and a bit stuck with the end....

```
    int number;
    number = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    int [] Days;
    Days = new int [12];
    Days [0] = 31;
    Days [1] = 28;
    Days [2] = 31;
    Days [3] = 30;
    Days [4] = 31;
    Days [5] = 30;
    Days [6] = 31;
    Days [7] = 31;
    Days [8] = 30;
    Days [9] = 31;
    Days [10] = 30;
    Days [11] = 31;
    jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(Days));


    String [] Month;
    Month = new String [12];
    Month [0] = "January";
    Month [1] = "February";
    Month [2] = "March";
    Month [3] = "April";
    Month [4] = "May";
    Month [5] = "June";
    Month [6] = "July";
    Month [7] = "August";
    Month [8] = "September";
    Month [9] = "October";
    Month [10] = "November";
    Month [11] = "December";
    jTextField2.setText(String.valueOf(Month));
```

Comment: What specifically are you stuck with? Please elaborate.

Also @JasonZ, his Days array holds the number of days in each month, so 12 is correct, as there are 12 months.

Comment: Naming conventions, please. Variables should be in camelCase. Don't start bad habits!

Comment: you probably want to output `String.valueOf(Month[number])` and `String.valueOf(Days[number])`

Comment: @wero note `Month` is already a `String[]`

Comment: @wero is correct, assuming an input of `0` is supposed to map to January. If January is inputted as `1`, use the index `number - 1`.

Comment: I'm stuck with the fact i'm making this program in a JFrame and this code is linked to an action button that when you enter a number for example in text field 1 you enter 1 and january and 31 is output to text field 2 and 3, i know i have to place something like number - 1 in there but im a bit confused at the minute...Thanks for the replies didn't think i'd get any help

Comment: Hey Guys just applied some of it there now...Thanks wero and bcsb1001 yours was the one just needed to put it as String.valueOf(Month[number - 1])...thanks again guys you helped alot

Answer (score 4):

A better version would be with class of Month:

```
public class Month {
    private String name;
    private int days;

    public Month() {}
    public Month(String name, int days) {
        this.name = name;
        this.days = days;        
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;   
    }

    public String getDays() {
        return days;   
    }

}


Month[] months = new Month[12];
months[0] = new Month("January", 31);
// ...

int n;
// ...user read from keyboard n from 1 to 12 month;

// set month info
jTextField.setText("In " + months[n - 1].getName() + " are " + months[n - 1].getDays() + " days!");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `number = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());` is a valid input (between 1 and 12) then you can do: `Days [number]` to get the days of that month as an integer and `Month [number]` to get the month name as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user input is a number between 1 and 12 (January is represented by 1 and December by 12), the month name is given by `Month[number - 1]` and the days of that month by `Days[number -1]`